# Retrieving Container IP address after `lxc start`

Tags: lxd

I have the following script I'm running in cloud-init on my cloud provider. It grabs a container from another host on my network, starts it, and then attempts to forward a port on the host to the container:

```
lxc init ...
lxc remote add gateway 10.132.98.1:8099 --accept-certificate --password securpwd
lxc copy gateway:build-slave build-slave
lxc start build-slave
CONTAINER_IP=$(lxc list "build-slave" -c 4 | awk '!/IPV4/{ if ( $2 != "" ) print $2}')
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 2200 -j DNAT --to ${CONTAINER_IP}
```

The only problem is that there is an arbitrary delay between when `lxc start` returns and when the `IPV4` info is available.  My current solution is to add `sleep 5s` after the `lxc start` command, but I'm worried that if my server is under load, it might actually be longer than 5 seconds before the container is initialized.

Is there a better solution that doesn't rely on an arbitrary wait period?

Comment: How about a loop? Get IP, is empty? then delay, repeat.

Comment: lxd provides a network proxy device for forwarding traffic: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/containers.md#type-proxy

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks! That's exactly the functionality I need, could write that up as an answer so I can give you rep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lawrence pointed out in the comments, LXD provides a "proxy" `device` that can be set on the container. In this way, I don't have to know the container's IP address in order to setup the correct IPTABLES entry. LXD will instead setup my proxy rule for me when the container I specify starts.

I configured this like so:

```
DROPLET_PUB_IP=$(ip -f inet addr show ens3 | sed -En -e 's/.*inet ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p')
lxc config device add build-slave ssh-slave proxy listen=tcp:${DROPLET_PUB_IP}:2200 connect=tcp:localhost:22
```